# Issue in displaying div using Colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colorbox

Good Day Professionals,

I'm using Colorbox plugin to display a certain div, but this issue appears.

the structure is as follow:

1- Hidden div to be displayed

2- Show btn to display the div

When I click the btn for the first time the div is displayed without any problems, but when I press ESC btn to close it and return the previous step again and click the btn the colorbox opens but without showing the div

This is the HTML code

```
<div class="to_be_show">
    <!-- html structure is here -->
</div>
<p class="display">display</p>
```

This is the css style

```
.to_be_show{ width: 500px; height: 200px; background: red; display: none; }
```

This is the JS code

```
$('.display').click(function(){ $('.to_be_show').css('display','block'); });
$('.display').colorbox({opacity: 0.98,inline:true});
$(document).bind('cbox_closed', function() {$('.to_be_show').css('display','none'); });
```

So, What is the problem with my code ?!

-------- **Update** ----------

**I know The problem but I don't know how to solve it !!!**

I want to set the **href** attr of the display with Jquery as the content is loaded dynamically

and i use this and didn't work !!!

```
$('.show_album').colorbox({href:$(this).prev()});
```

Why ??!!

Comment: Please provide http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: You seem to be missing the code for the ESC event handler and the colorbox

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating inline color box

**HTML Mark up**

```
<div style="display:none">
    <div class="to_be_show" id="to_be_show">
        Element to be show
    </div>
</div>
<a href="#to_be_show" class="inline cboxElement">Display</a>
```

**css**

```
.to_be_show {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}
```

**Js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".inline").colorbox({
        inline: true,
        opacity: 0.98,
    });
});
```

Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravi441988/7E42p/).

Don't forget to include
colorbox css & js
cheers!!!

Comment: OK, I'll try it and give your my feedback, Thanks.